# PHP DateTime Timedifference only correct in UTC Timezone?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

Can anybody explain me following behaviours:

```
$end = new DateTime("2015-03-01", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
$start = new DateTime("2015-02-01", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
$diff = $start->diff($end);
//result: DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 0 [d] => 28 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [invert] => 0 [days] => 28 )
```

If I don't use a timezone or Europe/Berlin I get wrong time diffs. 28 days is indeed correct, but in this case it's a month.

```
$end = new DateTime("2015-03-01", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$start = new DateTime("2015-02-01", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$diff = $start->diff($end);
//result: DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 1 [d] => 0 [h] => 0 [i] =>; 0 [s] => 0 [invert] => 0 [days] => 28 )
```

with UTC it works

```
$end = new DateTime("2015-04-01", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
$start = new DateTime("2015-03-01", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
$diff = $start->diff($end);
//result: DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 1 [d] => 3 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [invert] => 0 [days] => 31 )
```

1 month and 3 days?!? February, are you spooking here?

```
$end = new DateTime("2015-04-01", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$start = new DateTime("2015-03-01", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$diff = $start->diff($end);
//result: DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 1 [d] => 0 [h] => 0 [i] =>; 0 [s] => 0 [invert] => 0 [days] => 31 )
```

31 days = 1 month, UTC is correct

```
$end = new DateTime("2015-05-01", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
$start = new DateTime("2015-04-01", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
$diff = $start->diff($end);
//result: DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 0 [d] => 30 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [invert] => 0 [days] => 30 )
```

30 days are for Europe not a month as well?

```
$end = new DateTime("2015-05-01", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$start = new DateTime("2015-04-01", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$diff = $start->diff($end);
//result: DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 1 [d] => 0 [h] => 0 [i] =>; 0 [s] => 0 [invert] => 0 [days] => 30 )
```

UTC correct

```
$end = new DateTime("2015-06-01", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
$start = new DateTime("2015-05-01", new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
$diff = $start->diff($end);
//result: DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 1 [d] => 1 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [invert] => 0 [days] => 31 )
```

again 31 days, correct one month, but why +1 day?

```
$end = new DateTime("2015-06-01", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$start = new DateTime("2015-05-01", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$diff = $start->diff($end);
//result: DateInterval Object ( [y] => 0 [m] => 1 [d] => 0 [h] => 0 [i] =>; 0 [s] => 0 [invert] => 0 [days] => 31 )
```

UTC still correct

I don't get it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: And whats the problem over here..

Comment: I don't understand the different results.

Comment: Not a PHP guy, but try adding 12:00 to all of these dates. Just a hunch.

Comment: uh nice! Adding 12:00:00 fixes the issue! :) Hmmmm perhaps it's a daylight saving time issue? But both DateTimes are in the same Timezone, so this shouldn't be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are experiencing a known bug.

See:

- [PHP::Bug #52480  Incorrect difference using DateInterval](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52480)

Comment: thank you! so this bug is known since 5 years :D so the solution is currently really to calculate in UTC :)