# wrong count on php date_diff

Tags: php, datediff

I'm doing a date-diff on 2015-03-01 and 2017-01-31 (using php7.2) and it returns 1 year, 11 months and 2 days. But it should (obviously) be either 11 months and 0 days or 10 months and 30 days.

Why is that? Please don't tell me, that php is dividing by 30 or something - I don't need a calendar-function if it is less reliable than a manual solution!.. that would be just crazy, right?

```php
$diff = date_create('2015-03-01')->diff(date_create('2017-01-31'));
// returns
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 1
    [m] => 11
    [d] => 2
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 702
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)
// and that's simply just wrong
```

**UPDATE**
it works when switching the timezone from 'Europe/Berlin' to 'UTC'

```php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

but yeah, 'Europe/Berlin' should actually work, too...

Comment: Welcome to working with dates at the end of the month

Comment: Uhm, thx for downvoting the question, but how about some explanation and/or solution? i mean: the result is still just plain wrong, and there's no excuse for that, am i right? - by solution i mean something to get date_diff reliable, i sure know how to solve it manually myself.

Comment: @JohnConde you know, 10 months and 31 days would be fine, really! because that wouldn't be wrong...

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? With 7.3.4 the result is 1 year, 10 months and 30 days using your code (and fixing your syntax since what you posted will not work). You're missing a `)` on your statement.

Comment: @Dave oops (bracket fixed). i'm running it on 7.2 (as stated) on a windows-machine while the actual project runs on a debian but on php 5.6. (yeah - i know..) - hmm.. so does that mean that php fixed it with 7.3 or is it some weird machine-thing?

Comment: Can't tell you for sure but the [online PHP testers](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) are all coming back with the same 1 year, 10 months and 30 days with 5.6 and 7.2 and pretty much everything in between.

Comment: @Dave your answer did let me test one more thing: got it, well not really, cause its still wrong where it shouldnt, but it works when i switch timezone from 'Europe/Berlin' to 'UTC'

Comment: You now understand John Conde's first comment to your question. When dealing with dates and times you almost always want to use UTC. The result you were seeing was not really wrong given the timezone being used.

Comment: @Dave uhm - nah. 1st: i sure do want to use the right (the users!) timezone in order to recieve expected results. any calculation should consider daylightsavingtime etc.. 2nd: 11m+2d is just wrong. in any timezone. even if you assume that your sever traveled around the globe passing date-line several times ;) if i'm wrong here, please explain. 3rd: John was about not calculating from 1st of a month to the 1st of a month, as i understand it, and while this is sure a tricky mess, it's not about that problem at all, i guess he didn't realize, that the result is not just not expected, but wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just a bug. known, old, never solved. at least it was re-opened in 2017...

[PHP DateTime Timedifference only correct in UTC Timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592498/php-datetime-timedifference-only-correct-in-utc-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

While reading the php.net documentation [comments about this function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php#107434), I found a solution that seems to work. Someone rewrote the diff() function for PHP 5.2 and older versions.

Result: **1 year 10 months 30 days** (but you can modify it to be inclusive)

Definitely not the most elegant solution, but I hope this helps.

```
<?php

echo get_timespan_string(new Datetime('2015-03-01'), new Datetime('2017-01-31'));

function get_timespan_string($older, $newer) { 
  $Y1 = $older->format('Y'); 
  $Y2 = $newer->format('Y'); 
  $Y = $Y2 - $Y1; 

  $m1 = $older->format('m'); 
  $m2 = $newer->format('m'); 
  $m = $m2 - $m1; 

  $d1 = $older->format('d'); 
  $d2 = $newer->format('d'); 
  $d = $d2 - $d1; 

  $H1 = $older->format('H'); 
  $H2 = $newer->format('H'); 
  $H = $H2 - $H1; 

  $i1 = $older->format('i'); 
  $i2 = $newer->format('i'); 
  $i = $i2 - $i1; 

  $s1 = $older->format('s'); 
  $s2 = $newer->format('s'); 
  $s = $s2 - $s1; 

  if($s < 0) { 
    $i = $i -1; 
    $s = $s + 60; 
  } 
  if($i < 0) { 
    $H = $H - 1; 
    $i = $i + 60; 
  } 
  if($H < 0) { 
    $d = $d - 1; 
    $H = $H + 24; 
  } 
  if($d < 0) { 
    $m = $m - 1; 
    $d = $d + get_days_for_previous_month($m2, $Y2); 
  } 
  if($m < 0) { 
    $Y = $Y - 1; 
    $m = $m + 12; 
  } 
  $timespan_string = create_timespan_string($Y, $m, $d, $H, $i, $s); 
  return $timespan_string; 
} 

function get_days_for_previous_month($current_month, $current_year) { 
  $previous_month = $current_month - 1; 
  if($current_month == 1) { 
    $current_year = $current_year - 1; //going from January to previous December 
    $previous_month = 12; 
  } 
  if($previous_month == 11 || $previous_month == 9 || $previous_month == 6 || $previous_month == 4) { 
    return 30; 
  } 
  else if($previous_month == 2) { 
    if(($current_year % 4) == 0) { //remainder 0 for leap years 
      return 29; 
    } 
    else { 
      return 28; 
    } 
  } 
  else { 
    return 31; 
  } 
} 

function create_timespan_string($Y, $m, $d, $H, $i, $s) 
{ 
  $timespan_string = ''; 
  $found_first_diff = false; 
  if($Y >= 1) { 
    $found_first_diff = true; 
    $timespan_string .= pluralize($Y, 'year').' '; 
  } 
  if($m >= 1 || $found_first_diff) { 
    $found_first_diff = true; 
    $timespan_string .= pluralize($m, 'month').' '; 
  } 
  if($d >= 1 || $found_first_diff) { 
    $found_first_diff = true; 
    $timespan_string .= pluralize($d, 'day').' '; 
  } 
  if($H >= 1 || $found_first_diff) { 
    $found_first_diff = true; 
    $timespan_string .= pluralize($H, 'hour').' '; 
  } 
  if($i >= 1 || $found_first_diff) { 
    $found_first_diff = true; 
    $timespan_string .= pluralize($i, 'minute').' '; 
  } 
  if($found_first_diff) { 
    $timespan_string .= 'and '; 
  } 
  $timespan_string .= pluralize($s, 'second'); 
  return $timespan_string; 
} 

function pluralize( $count, $text ) 
{ 
  return $count . ( ( $count == 1 ) ? ( " $text" ) : ( " ${text}s" ) ); 
}
```

Comment: thanx, there are also quite some workarounds/alternative ways around here (and i just quickly hacked one myself, according to my needs), but i found no explanation about that error, nor solution for using date_diff without that error